# Python 3.0 IDE - Komodo and Eclipse both flaky?

Tags: python, ide

I'm trying to find a decent IDE that supports Python 3.x, and offers code completion/in-built Pydocs viewer, Mercurial integration, and SSH/SFTP support.

Anyhow, I'm trying Pydev, and I open up a .py file, it's in the Pydev perspective and the Run As doesn't offer any options. It does when you start a Pydev project, but I don't want to start a project just to edit one single Python script, lol, I want to just open a .py file and have It Just Work...

Plan 2, I try Komodo 6 Alpha 2. I actually quite like Komodo, and it's nice and snappy, offers in-built Mercurial support, as well as in-built SSH support (although it lacks SSH HTTP Proxy support, which is slightly annoying).

However, for some reason, this refuses to pick up Python 3. In Edit-Preferences-Languages, there's two option, one for Python and Python3, but the Python3 one refuses to work, with either the official Python.org binaries, or ActiveState's own ActivePython 3. Of course, I can set the "Python" interpreter to the 3.1 binary, but that's an ugly hack and breaks Python 2.x support.

So, does anybody who uses an IDE for Python have any suggestions on either of these accounts, or can you recommend an alternate IDE for Python 3.0 development?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [PyCharm from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/).

Comment: PyCharm is just a stripped-down IDEA IntelliJ which brings my computer to the crawl. Besides performance issues, user interface can be a little buggy sometimes -- like after changing a setting, you can't click Apply.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention these so I'm not sure if you've tried them but there are:
- Aptana (aptana.com)
- The Eric Python IDE (http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/)
- WingWare Python IDE (wingware.com)

I haven't used any of them so I don't know if they will match your needs, but I'd expected them to be pretty close as they are all mature.

As for PyCharm, I've been using it for a while and it's fine, actully I like it very much.
However I'm a Python noob and probably do not use many advanced features so YMMV.